Getting file path by inode and serial number on macOS
I'm currently working on a Rust program where I need to retrieve a file's path by its inode and volume serial number, similar to how the GetFileInfo utility works in Xcode.
For example, in a macOS, after creating a file (hello.txt) and then renaming it (mv hello.txt world.txt), you can use GetFileInfo to retrieve the new file path:
$ /usr/bin/GetFileInfo /.vol/16777229/25468225
file: "/Users/user/world.txt"

The file's inode and volume serial number can be retrieved from the output of the stat command:
$ stat hello.txt
16777229 25468225 -rw-r--r-- 1 user staff 0 6 "May 13 22:09:46 2024" "May 13 22:09:45 2024" "May 13 22:09:45 2024" "May 13 22:09:45 2024" 4096 8 0 hello.txt

I'd like to achieve similar functionality in Rust. Is there a Rust library or a combination of libraries that can help me achieve this? If not, what would be the best approach to implement this functionality in Rust?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You can always spawn a process for GetFileInfo.

For Linux at least this seems impossible.

GetFileInfo is available only if xcode installed.
Seems like it uses developer.apple.com/nsurl/bookmarkdata internally, so I'm still checking how to implement it in Rust.
As for Windows, I found working poc in ExtendedFileAPIs.cpp

@ChayimFriedman you can find -inum but it's not all that useful or performant.

I found a solution and created a Rust crate that achieves cross-platform functionality. In short, on Windows, it uses GetFileByID, and on macOS, it uses the .vol directory and fcntl with F_GETPATH.
You can find the crate here: refind.
